# redirect my domain to my vps server in hostinger does not work

Tags: node.js, web, dns, subdomain, vps

i have my website with express and node .js, and i have an vps in hostinger, i have a domain but i dont know how to redirect the domain to my website with the port, my code in my server.js is this:

```
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3080;
const app = express();
const hbs = require('hbs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const path = require("path");

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dexia_sprite.ico')))

 
//bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

//HBS
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');




//rutas
app.use(require('./routes/index')); 
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Corriendo en el puerto ${port}`));
```

in the folder public_html, if i put a .html file it load right, but i dont know how to say that it have to load the server, which is in the port 3080, i recive an error 404, but if i enter the website with the ip, it works, what can i do?? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If You added DNS records properly ( there is a how-to on hostinger site ), then i guess the problem is your the port. You have to forward requests incomming  on port 80 to your express server which runs on port 3080. When a browser requests a website, it does it on typical ports, like 80 or 443 so the server that runs on your VPS shoud listen on those ports.

Easiest way is to simply run your express app on port 80, so that it will automatically get any HTTP requests sent to your VPS.

Comment: Yes it works, thanks